# Website development - Which tools and languages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

for a project I will need to develop a website. The problem is: This is the first time for me.

I am currently planning and drawing the outlines and also trying to find out which technique will suit the project best and how to approach this task.

The website should retrieve data from an API by using RESTful HTTP-Commands and present the results to the registered user.

My programming experience so far is mainly C++ and some C#/.NET which I used for the creating the API.

So, which language and script do you think would suit best? I have looked into ASP.NET MVC a bit because of my previous experience with .NET. Is that a proper choice?
Apart from
 that, I would prefer a graphical designer for the HTML-coding. What tools would you use? I looked into Google Web Designer, but I was not quite persuaded. What would you recommend?

Thanks in advance!
Eteokles

Comment: Hi, apparently my question has recieved two negative points. I apologise if my posting does not meet certain requirements or quality standards. If there is a valid reason for downvoting, please tell me so it can be improved. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Sami, if you have basic knowledge in CSharp/.Net it is not a bad idea to use ASP.NET MVC/API to setup your project. But you should bear platform dependence in mind if you are not using .NET Core, which is actually in Version 1.0.0 RC 2. So if you use ASP.NET 4 you will have to use a Microsoft Server to deploy your application. If that is no problem for you, then I would recommend to have a look at [Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/training-topics/web-development#!jobf=Developer&lang=1033). Developing ASP.NET applications with Visual Studio is a pleasure, you have great debugging tools and you can create [Unit Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182526%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to test your application.

Unfortunately there is nothing like a graphical designer for your HTML frontend in Visual Studio. But if you are using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) you can reach your design goals really fast. Also Bootstrap is "mobile first" which means, that even if a user accesses your Website over a mobile device (Tablet, Smartphone) the site will look great. The basic ASP.NET 4 MVC template comes with a Bootstrap layout, you could build upon.

If you want to enable users of your application to create user accounts you can choose the ASP.NET MVC template with "individual user account" [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

In conclusion I want to provide you another link where ASP.NET is compared to another very popular and easy to learn language for developing websites [PHP vs. ASP.NET](https://blog.udemy.com/php-vs-asp-net/). I would recommend ASP.NET after using PHP for years, because thinks like [asynchronous programming](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx) and using [Entity-Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907) to handle your database needs.

I would also recommend you to do further reading on the pros and cons of different tools and languages and after you have a general overview over the available solutions you should compare which language and which tools match your application needs most. Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate reply, I really appreciate it. A microsoft server for deployment is no problem at all. I have not even thought about mobile devices that much, thanks for adding that!

Comment: @MichaelHeribert You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your experience/knowledge, ASP.Net, MVC and API seems a good to go option. You might need to understand Javascript/jQuery and JSON to communicate with API. It's pretty simple like:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/api/products", function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
    });
})
```

For UI, Bootstrap is always a good choice and easily get your layout at
[Layoutit](http://www.layoutit.com)

For Web API, a good tutorial found at  [Web API in ASP.Net MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/how-to-create-web-api-in-Asp-Net-mvc/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will take a look at the link :) It really did!